# How to convert PatternLayout to JsonLayout using KeyValuePair?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j

I have this property in log4j2.xml: 
%d [%t] %-5p %X{requestId} %c - %m%n

and would like to have it in json format using: key="Date" value="%d"

Comment: See: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Comment: I am a little unclear on your question. Could you please clarify?  Are you wanting to use the PatternLayout to generate JSON or do you want to use the JsonLayout and be able to include a field named Date in it?

Comment: Just i want to know how map the values of patternLayout (%d [%t] %-5p %X{requestId} %c - %m%n) to JsonLayout using KeyValuePair . @rgoers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would include a Key/Value pair using the Date Lookup as

```
<JsonLayout>
  <KeyValuePair key="Date" value="$${date:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}"/>
</JsonLayout>
```

This will cause the date and time to be evaluated on every event. Note that this is considerably slower than how Log4j calculates and prints the time in the LogEvent.

Comment: What you have written is totally correct. Is it possible to parse the rest of property for example %m%n ?